# codeigniter javascript timer setting to localstorage

Tags: javascript, timer, local-storage

FYI: I'm still learning javascript.

I have this timer I'm trying to build. Eventually, it will be set for 12 or 24 hours, but right now its set to 10 seconds. I'm trying to get it to set `localStorage` for this timer and makes sure it doesn't reload and lose the time if the user leaves the page. So basically, when the user presses the button, it starts the countdown, after the countdown it will update the database, so i need to make it that when they start the timer, it continues till it finishes, even if the user leaves and comes back hours later.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function Timer(duration, display) {
    let timer = duration,
      hours, minutes, seconds;
      
    localStorage.setItem("timr", timer);

    let setIntervalId = setInterval(function() {


      hours = parseInt((timer / 3600) % 24, 10)
      minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10)
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      

      hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;


      display.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

      --timer;
      if (timer === -1) {
        clearInterval(setIntervalId);
        // Perform the necessary operation here like triggering event to update the database.
        var nat = window.prompt("Nation Name", "Temp-");



      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  function start() {
    // For testing purpose set the value to 10 seconds.


    var htime = localStorage.getItem("timr");
    
    if (htime < 0 ) {
      let test = 10;
      let twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60;
      const display = $('#remainingTime');
      Timer(test, display);
    } else {
      let temp = htime;
      const display = $('#remainingTime');
      Timer(temp, display);
    }

  }

</script>

<span id="remainingTime"></span>
<br>
<button onclick="start()">Start Nation</button>
<br>
<br/><input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Doing this gets back this error:

> NaN:NaN:Nan

Heres the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abrasaxaz/z3fn84wb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is no previous `timr` item in the localStorage, it will return `null`, so you should handle that instead of the previous value being negative.

```
if (htime == null) {
```

You also need to set the localStorage value in the `setInterval` callback and remove the item when the timer ends.

```
//...
--timer;
localStorage.setItem("timr", timer)
if (timer === -1) {
    clearInterval(setIntervalId);
    // Perform the necessary operation here like triggering event to update the database.
    var nat = window.prompt("Nation Name", "Temp-");
    localStorage.removeItem("timr");
}
//...
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2von9mbu/)

Comment: @abrasaxaz The JSFiddle example works fine for me. Are you sure it produces that? Or have you edited something?

Comment: all i did is load your example and pressed the button. still returned it. let me load it onto the site and test it

Comment: yeah so i put it on the site, it is loading, but when i reload the page, the timer pauses and resumes when the button is pressed again, how do i keep it running even on refresh?